# React map redux state to create multiple components within a component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, mapbox-gl-js

I am using the [react-redux-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/yunluyl/react-redux-mapbox-gl) library. I have an array of spots that I want to map in order to create multiple overlay components within the Mapbox Component. However on trying to map the array I always get an undefined error. I am new to React/Redux so am not sure what the issue is.

My Component Below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Mapbox from 'react-redux-mapbox-gl';

import SpotsOverlay from './SpotsOverlay'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  spots: state.homemap.spots
})

class HomeMap extends React.Component {

    render(){

    return (

    <Mapbox
      mapboxgl={mapboxgl}
      accessToken={mapAccessToken}
      getMap={this.getMap}
      style={this.mapStyle}
      options={this.mapOptions}
    >

      {
      this.props.spots.map(spot =>{
        return (
          <SpotsOverlay
            overlay={this.overlay}
            key={spot.id}/>
        );
      })
     }

    </Mapbox>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: it should be `this.props.spots...` not `props.spots.`

Comment: @MayankShukla I have tried this previously still doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: are you hitting any api to get that data ??

Comment: Yeah a localhost: I will edit and add the other code

Comment: put the check on the value before using `map`, like this: `Array.isArray(this.props.sports) && this.props.sports.map` or set the initial state in reducer as `[]`, it should work.

Comment: @MayankShukla Actually that worked great. Thanks so much!

Comment: reason why is was failing without condition is, initially reducer state is `{}`, so `state.homemap.spots` will be **undefined** and when you were using map of `undefined`, it was throwing the error, glad it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the mapping outside of the return method might help.

```
class HomeMap extends React.Component {

    render(){

        let spots = [];

        if(this.props.spots) {
            spots = this.props.spots.map(spot =>{
                return (
                    <SpotsOverlay
                        overlay={this.overlay}
                        key={spot.id}/>
                );
            });
        }

        return (

            <Mapbox
                mapboxgl={mapboxgl}
                accessToken={mapAccessToken}
                getMap={this.getMap}
                style={this.mapStyle}
                options={this.mapOptions}
            >
                {spots}
            </Mapbox>
        );
    }
}
```

As @MayankShukla said in his comment, the reason why this works better is that

> initially reducer state is {}, so state.homemap.spots will be undefined and when you were using map of undefined

Comment: small suggestion, always mention, what you changed and why it will help everyone :)

Comment: @MayankShukla I'm not sure why it helps, I just remember that I ran into a similar problem when I started out with react and this solved it. But one thing is that it looks much cleaner at least. :)

Comment: explained here, check why it will solve the error, to use map variable should be a array otherwise it will throw error,  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922017/react-map-redux-state-to-create-multiple-components-within-a-component#comment76821491_44922017)